# Do monks HAVE to accept anything offered to them?

Tags: theravada, ethics, technology

Does a theravada abbott have to accept everything / anything that is offered to them? I'm referencing technology, things beyond requisites.

I know it is important for abbotts to set a good example and to create trust through their actions.

Comment: No. Receiving is generally voluntary, if good, always out of compassion, if asked to. There are of cause things not allowed to accept and other criterias to reject offerings sometimes, good householder.

Comment: A teaching story of Ven. Kassapa, casting away a Deva eager after doing merits: [The Story of Lajadevadhita](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.09.bpit_en.html#s-dhp-118) And there are many other stories where those with much merits (mostly Gods) where cast away or rebuked for taking poors the possibility to make Dana

Comment: Today many monks reject gifts because they live still a householderlife, order, hold money and take of what is not given... that's of course a very bad way but no way to change their modes.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the Pratimoksha followed by Theraadans, however, according the the Pratimoksha of Mulasarvastivada (which I foillwed when I was a monk), there are certain items no monk can possess (e.g. a meditation mat made of black sheep's wool) - so if offered, one might accept it - but then turn it over to the abbot. Otherwise, the only other relevant vows concerned accepting what was offered in terms of food. I imagine these restrictions would be similar for Theravadans. As for technology, in my monastery, we had lots of teachings that had been digitized, for walkmen, MP3 players and computers were ubiquitous.

Hope this helps.